# Como indicar apenas um elemento em funções onMouseEnter no REACTJS

Tags: javascript, react

Preciso fazer que, quando passarmos o mouse (hover) em um link, seja mostrado apenas um objeto, não vários.

Meu código abaixo:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

   //importando components estilizados
   import { NavUl, NavLi, Plug45Deg } from "./style/menuStyle";

class Menu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);



    //estados 
    this.state = {
      isHovered: false
    };
  }

  handleEnter() {
    this.setState({
      isHovered: true
    });
  }

  handleLeave() {
    this.setState({
      isHovered: false
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <NavUl>
          <NavLi
            onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter.bind(this)}
            onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave.bind(this)}
          >
            {this.state.isHovered ? <Plug45Deg /> : <div />}
            <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
          </NavLi>
          <NavLi
            onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter.bind(this)}
            onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave.bind(this)}
          >
            {this.state.isHovered ? <Plug45Deg /> : <div />}
            <NavLink to="/sobre">Sobre</NavLink>
          </NavLi>
          <NavLi
            onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter.bind(this)}
            onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave.bind(this)}
          >
            {this.state.isHovered ? <Plug45Deg /> : <div />}
            <NavLink to="/portfolio">Portfólio</NavLink>
          </NavLi>
          <NavLi
            onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter.bind(this)}
            onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave.bind(this)}
          >
            {this.state.isHovered ? <Plug45Deg /> : <div />}
            <NavLink to="/blog">Blog</NavLink>
          </NavLi>
          <NavLi
            onMouseEnter={this.handleEnter.bind(this)}
            onMouseLeave={this.handleLeave.bind(this)}
          >
            {this.state.isHovered ? <Plug45Deg /> : <div />}
            <NavLink to="/contato">Contato</NavLink>
          </NavLi>
        </NavUl>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

[image: Resultado do código acima.]

Comment: Fala Guilherme, quais objetos está querendo que apareça e quais estão aparecendo.. não consegui compreender muito bem.

Comment: Daniel, seguinte... essse ícone de plug é o elemento que eu queria que aparecesse apenas um por vez, em cada elemento do menu com o hover, porém, quando passo o mouse em cima.. aparece 1 elemento em cima de cada item, todos de uma vez só!

Comment: Guilherme, é porque você tem apenas um estado para todos os componentes. Você poderia dar um ID para cada um ou nome mesmo e comparar, saca? Vou tentar montar algo aqui e respondo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guilherme, o estado está para todos os componentes. Você precisa testar de outra forma usando um nome do componente. Vou tentar reproduzir seu código com as instruções:

```js
import React from "react";
    import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

   //importando components estilizados
   import { NavUl, NavLi, Plug45Deg } from "./style/menuStyle";

class Menu extends React.Component {
    //estados
    state = {
      isHovered: "",
    };
  }
  // usando arrow functions não precisa fazer o bind
  handleEnter = (name) => {
    this.setState({
      isHovered: name
    });
  }

  handleLeave = () => {
    this.setState({
      isHovered: "",
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <nav>
        <NavUl>
          <NavLi
            onMouseEnter={() => this.handleEnter('home')}
            onMouseLeave={() => this.handleLeave()}
          >
            {this.state.isHovered === 'home' ? <Plug45Deg /> : <div />}
            <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
          </NavLi>
          ...
        </NavUl>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu
```

Comment: Perfeito... funcionou aqui! agora é só iterar isso e pegar de um array os dados da rota... valeu